# zlib binary size: static vs dynamic

Tags: c, dll, static, size, zlib

While playing with zlib (with mingw, plain C99, no C++), I saw that the zlib.dll is only 100K while statically linking the zlib source (with Z_SOLO defined) grows my executable size by about 1MO!

Can you light me on the raisons of this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you *only* link the zlib library statically, or also all of its dependencies?

Comment: @Igor simple curiosité... :p

Comment: @KerrekSB what are zlib dependencies? I only added all zlib sources to a simple testing C project (under CodeBlocks) and compiled.

Edit: I compiled as release, with -Os